# Когда в c# class не совсем class?

Tags: c#, .net

В одном проекте разбирал багу. Эта бага была связана с тем, что проект прошел некоторую техническую итерацию,  т.е. бизнес логика в нём  не поменялась, но в него была добавлена технология, которая неявно поменяла поведение кода, оставив его представление неизменным. И связано это именно с тем, что в некоторых случая class бывает не совсем class-ом.
Лабораторная по анализу этого бага приобрела форму задачки на знание технологии .NET.
Таким образом, прошу оценить формулировку задачки и её актуальность.
Ну, и если захотите, можете представить её решение. :)

**Задачка**

Есть код консольного приложения на c#:

```
#region Здесь код изменять нельзя
public sealed class ClassA
{
    private int _value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
#endregion

#region Здесь код изменять нельзя
public sealed class ClassB
#endregion
#region Здесь код изменять нельзя
{
    public void Do(ref ClassA a)
    {
        a.Value = 5;
    }
}
#endregion

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region Для класс Program изменять код только здесь
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        #endregion

        bool result = Process(b);

        System.Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static bool Process(ClassB b)
    {
        ClassA a1 = new ClassA();
        ClassA a2 = a1;

        b.Do(ref a2);

        return a1.Value == a2.Value;
    }
}
```

Запустив его на исполнение мы увидим, что  метод `Program.Process` вернёт значение `true` и на консоль будет выведен текст «true».

Используя стандартный функционал .NET Framework (версией >= 2.0)  допишите код для классов `ClassA` и `ClassB`, а также измените код в методе Program.Main, чтобы метод `Program.Process` вернул значение `false` и, соответственно, на консоль должно быть выведено «false».
Код в регионах `#region Здесь код изменять нельзя` менять нельзя. Для класса Program код можно поменять только в регионе `region Для класс Program изменять код только здесь`.

**UPD** Спасибо @DreamChild
Директивы условной компиляции C# не применять.

**UPD**
Хотел бы ещё раз уточнить, что нужно только дописать ClassA и ClassB, т.е. не нужно создавать новые классы.

**UPD**  [Ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/414985/11230) дал @hazzik
Суть в том, что выполнение функционал класса `ClassB` перевели в другой домен. Но при этом неявно поменялась логика работы метода `ClassB.Do(ref ClassA)` и экземпляр типа ClassA уже передаётся не как ссылочный объект, а как значимый объект, т.е. в результате сериализации получается структура значений полей класса ClassA, которая передается через границу домена. При выходе из метода `ClassB.Do(ref ClassA)` возвращается структура полей класс ClassA и, самое интересное, эта структура десериализуется в новый объект, ссылка на который и записывается в переменную `a2`. Таким образом, в `a1` и в `a2` получаются ссылки на два разных объекта, при чём, значения их внутренних полей различаются.

Comment: Как дописать код для `ClassA`, если он в регионе `Здесь код изменять нельзя`, и создавать новые классы (в том числе статические, с extension-методами) тоже нельзя?

Comment: @Dmitry люди в ответах дописывают. Классы ClassA и ClassB нужно дописать. Дополнительных классов или структур создавать не надо.

Comment: Значит у вас регионы на `ClassA` неправильные, потому что его код никак нельзя дописать, даже с помощью partial class

Comment: @MaLS Вы пишете *нужно только дописать ClassA и ClassB*. Мой вопрос намекает вам о невозможности этого по условию задачи. Перечитайте, пожалуйста, его еще раз. Кстати, ни в одном из ответов класс `ClassA` не изменен.

Comment: @Dmirty ClassA можно дописать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То же самое, что и предыдущий мой ответ, только все это делаем средствами .NET fx, т.е. используем его прокси и, соответственно, все вызываем из отдельного домена:

```
[Serializable]
#region Здесь код изменять нельзя
public sealed class ClassA
{
    private int _value;

    public int Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }
}
#endregion

#region Здесь код изменять нельзя
public sealed class ClassB
#endregion
    : MarshalByRefObject 
#region Здесь код изменять нельзя
{
    public void Do(ref ClassA a)
    {
        a.Value = 5;
    }
}

#endregion

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        #region Для класс Program изменять код только здесь
        ClassB b = (ClassB) AppDomain.CreateDomain("X").CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(typeof(ClassB).Assembly.CodeBase, typeof(ClassB).FullName);
        #endregion

        bool result = Process(b);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }

    public static bool Process(ClassB b)
    {
        ClassA a1 = new ClassA();
        ClassA a2 = a1;

        b.Do(ref a2);

        return a1.Value == a2.Value;
    }
}
```

Почему так происходит? `ClassA` не помечен для маршаллинга через границу доменов с передачей по ссылке (то, что делает `MarshalByRefObject`), по-этому он будет сериализован до передачи в домен "X" и в домене "X" десериализован в новый объект. Для внешнего домена никто никогда не изменял a1 его `Value` так и останется 0. При возвращении из домена "X" экземпляр класса `ClassA` будет сериализован и десериализован уже в обратном направлении и присвоен переменной `a2`.

Если у параметра `a` метода `ClassB`.`Do` убрать модификатор `ref` то картина будет немного иной: обратной десериализации из "X" в текущий домен происходить не будет, и, следовательно, `a2` будет все-еще ссылаться на тот же объект, что и `a1`, а значение свойства `Value` этого объекта останется равным `0`.

Чтобы исправить эти "проблемы" нужно унаследовать `ClassA` от `MarshalByRefObject`.

Comment: Ответ верный. Только зачем Serializable установлен у ClassB?

Comment: [Serializable] у ClassB, потому что опыт - сын ошибок трудных.

Comment: По поводу актуальности "задачи", то мне кажется, что это просто-напросто баг в кросс-доменном запросе с ref параметрами. Примерно такого же плана, как в моем другом ответе

Comment: а по мне так проблема в определение class. Народ говорит, экземпляры типа class передаются в методы по ссылке, так вот это не всегда иногда они передаются по значению, как структуры.

Comment: Тут они не передаются по значению. объект класса `ClassA`, он сериализуется при передаче в другой домен, а там десериализуется, отсюда получается, что 2 разных объекта. Для того, чтобы решить эту проблему, нужно унаследовать `ClassA` от `MarshalByRefObject`

Comment: А я считаю, что когда ClassB отнаследовали от MarshalByRefObject, следовало пересмотреть всю логику этого класс. И обратить внимание на метод `void Do(ref ClassA a)`, так как здесь возникает вопрос о распределении ресурсов между доменами и где какой объект нужно создавать.

Answer (score 3):

Так задумано или тут дыра в регионах? )

```
#region Здесь код изменять нельзя
public sealed class ClassB
#endregion

    // сюда можно дописать что угодно, например:
    : BaseB
{
    public new void Do(ref ClassA a)
    {
        a = new ClassA();
        base.Do(ref a);
    }
}

public class BaseB
#region Здесь код изменять нельзя
{
    public void Do(ref ClassA a)
    {
        a.Value = 5;
    }
}
#endregion
```

Comment: прикольный вариант)

Comment: @THTP Да, так задумано. Но надо дописать ClassA и ClassB, а не создавать новые.

Comment: Дыра в регионах там чтобы использовать AOP, `public sealed class ClassB : System.ContextBoundObject`

Comment: @AlexShesterov В развитии бага именно это и было сделано.

Comment: Ответ не верный.

Answer (score 1):

`ClassB` наследуем от `System.MarshalByRefObject`

Пишем следующий прокси-класс:

```
class ClassBProxy : RealProxy
{
    public ClassBProxy() : base(typeof (ClassB))
    {
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        IMethodCallMessage call = msg as IMethodCallMessage;
        var args = call.Args;
        // Здесь мы подменяем ClassA на нужный нам
        args[0] = new ClassA {Value = 100};
        return new ReturnMessage(null, call.Args, call.Args.Length, call.LogicalCallContext, call);
    }
}
```

В Program.Main создаем ClassB вот так: `ClassB b = (ClassB) new ClassBProxy().GetTransparentProxy();`

Полный пример: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GbhXP5

Comment: Мыслите в правильном направлении. Но нужно только дописать ClassA и ClassB и изменить кое-что в методе Main. Создавать новые классы не нужно. Ответ не верный.

Comment: Код возвращает false, изменил я его только в регионах, где его можно было менять, что вас еще не устраивает? Вы хотите, чтобы мы научились читать мысли?

Comment: хочу проверить понимание формулировки задачи. Написано ведь "допишите код для классов ClassA и ClassB, а также измените код в методе Program.Main". Разве это не означает, что новые классы писать не надо? Может надо перефразировать?

Comment: Нет, не означает.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать это можно с помощью вот такого колдунства:

модифицируем класс ClassB таким образом:

```
#region Здесь код изменять нельзя
public sealed class ClassB
#endregion

#if SOME_FLAG 
// SOME_FLAG нигде  не определен, 
// а потому "старая" реализация метода Do 
// заменяется "новой" из ветки №else
#region Здесь код изменять нельзя
{
    public void Do(ref ClassA a)
    {
        a.Value = 5;
    }
}
#endregion

#else
{
    public void Do(ref ClassA a)
    {
        a = new ClassA();
        a.Value = 6;
    }
}
#endif
```

менять код в Main даже не потребовалось

Comment: Да. Возможно. Но в моем случае я попросил использовать технологии .NET. Хорошо. Добавлю в условие: условная компиляция не применяется.